# Website design - adjusting the size of picture

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, photo-editing

I have a stock photo, it's original size is 5616 × 3744 px.
I would like to change its size to be used for my web design in photoshop - to size 1600 x 600. I do not want to crop the image because I would loose some picture content -  if I crop e.g. the top half.
I tried to use in Photoshop Image - Image size function, but I found that with its proportion locked(aspect ratio) it's height is way too big. 
Could you please help me?

Comment: But surely this would just result in having a squashed image if you don't want to crop?

Comment: Unless scientists finally invent magic, with these restrictions, there's nothing you can do. You have to be willing to do some cropping or to leave empty space on either side of the image.

Comment: Unless you want to squash the proportions you cannot fit a ~12:7 aspect ratio into a 16:6 ratio. Btw you don't always need all of an image for people to understand it so cropping it *might* not be as bad as you think.

Comment: I gguuuuuess one compromise might be to animate the image within a container:  **[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/SRnV5/)**

Comment: I am reminded of the phrase, "you can't fit 10lbs of crap in a 5lb box"

Comment: @cclark413 I think Mythbusters tested that. If I remember correctly, they technically succeeded. It's just that when they weighted it afterwards, it was lighter cause most of the liquids had flown out from the cracks.

Comment: @joonas lol.  I guess that's what would happen to all those pixels then, too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid have to distort the image, you *will* have to crop it, at least partially. Since distorted images rarely look good, cropping is often unavoidable. You can reduce it to a minimum, though:

- Use `Image > Image Size...`
  (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>right
  Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to reduce the width of your image to 1600
  pixels. Make sure 'constrain proportions' is checked to avoid
  distortion.

You'll end up with an image 1600 pixels wide and 1067 pixels high.

- Use the Crop tool (<kbd>C</kbd>) and type your desired dimensions in the two fields:

[image]

- Drag around the crop box to cut off part of top and bottom of your picture.
- Press <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd> or click the checkmark at the right side of the option bar to accept the crop.

If you think you're losing too much from the top and bottom, you might want to try and use Photoshop's photo editing tools (eg. content-aware move in 'Extend' modus) to add more content to the sides of your image before cropping. Good and convincing extension is hard, though.

Comment: Not only is good extension hard, it's also only possible with some types of images. Basically, some images are practically impossible to extend because of their content. (This is directed to any beginners that read your answer and decide they'll take a shot at extending the image.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case if you don't want to crop an Image then you had to squeeze it from height.
by unchecking the constrain proportion in the Image size menu.[image]