# How can i increase/decrease the width and height of an image without loss the quality and resolution

Tags: images, image-quality

I've an image with width 540 and height 255. I need this image to put in a website. So, that i want this image with width 347 and height 346. I tried with STOIK smart image resize tool, but it's give expected result. How can i do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this http://www.pixelmator.com/try/

Comment: It will support for windows OS? It seems for Mac OS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website design - adjusting the size of picture](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/30330/website-design-adjusting-the-size-of-picture)

Comment: Hi there! We need to know more about what you are trying to do to help you. How did you try to resize the image and why didn't it work?

Comment: why are you not using photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

As your image is 255px in height and you need 346, you'll aways loose some quality there. Also, your target image has a different aspect ratio (width / height) as your source image, so in addition to being pixelated you'll get a distorted image.
To resolve the latter issue, you could first crop the image to your target aspect ratio.